# Addressing another dataframe with dynamic variables in R (ideally dplyr, using mutate)

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr

I have already read a variety of threads on dynamically named variables, but I couldn't quite find an answer.

I have two dataframes.

```
df <- data.frame(qno=c(1,2,3,4))
ref <- data.frame(Q1 = c(1:20),Q2 = c(21:40),Q3=c(41:60),Q4 = c(61:80))
```

Now I want to create another column 'average' in the df dataframe which gives me the average of each column in ref.
Intended output:

```
df <- data.frame(qno=c(1,2,3,4), average = c(10.5,30.5,50.5,70.5))
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(average := mean(!!as.name(paste0("ref$Q",qno)))
```

I have also tried a version with a for loop, but that didn't work either.

```
for (i in 1:length(df$qno)){
  df$average[i] <- mean(as.name(paste0("ref$Q",df$qno[i])))
}
```

````
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(average = mean(as.name(paste0("ref$Q",qno))))```.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is with `mutate`:

```
df %>% mutate(average = t(ref %>% summarise(across(everything(),  ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))))

  qno average
1   1    10.5
2   2    30.5
3   3    50.5
4   4    70.5
```

But you can use it without `mutate` entirely if you want the names from `ref`:

```
t(ref %>% summarise(across(everything(), list(mean), .names = "{.col}"))) %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  rename(average = 1)

   average
Q1    10.5
Q2    30.5
Q3    50.5
Q4    70.5
```

Comment: Really like this approach! Do you know how to give the na.rm=TRUE argument to the mean function in your first suggested solution by any chance?

Comment: Yep! You would replace ```list(mean)``` with ```~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)```. Probably should have done that to begin with. Updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
ref <- data.frame(Q1 = c(1:20),Q2 = c(21:40),Q3=c(41:60),Q4 = c(61:80))
out <- data.frame(qno=c(1,2,3,4), average = c(10.5,30.5,50.5,70.5))    

df <- data.frame(qno=c(1:length(ref)))
    
for (i in seq_along(ref)) {
  df$average[i] <- mean(ref[[i]], na.rm = T)
  
}
```

I was not really sure if you want to name the rows like the variables, so you could just add this when you create the df object:

```
df <- data.frame(qno = paste0("Q", c(1:length(ref))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it did! Ideally I'd like to know how to use the names of the ref dataframe (as in my attempts), but I'm really glad that I now have something that works!